# Calculate growth when NA exists and different periods are available

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
june<- c(5,6,7)
may<- c(1,NA,1)
april<- c(2,2,2)
march<- c(3,3,NA)
feb<- c(4,NA,NA)
dt<-data.frame(june,may,april,march,feb)
```

Each row contains units of cumulative growth since previous month. I need to calculate growth rates using the following formula: june value minus the earliest available value, all divided by the total number of periods of the two values reduced by 1. That is for the first row it is (5-4)/4 because 5 and 4  values span a 5 month period which reduced by one is 4 , for the second row it is (6-3)/3 and for the third row it is (7-2)/2.
It is not a problem to do this if all values for feb exist. But I could not figure out how to do it when NA exist for feb and so on?  NA in the middle of a series is not a problem, but that month should be included when calculation to find the divisor is done. Thanks.

Comment: Should the months in your data set be considered in order? I mean from `feb` to `june`? It's not clear how you choose your month or on what order they are considered.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR If I understand your question  correctly: I need to always subtract from the june value the earliest available value which is most of the time is feb, but when NA exist it could be march and so on. Once I establish the latest and earliest value the values in between do not matter (except the periods matter for calculating the divisor).

Comment: I meant how the earliest value is defined? in terms of quantity or month? It appears `feb` values are closer to `june` values in terms of quantity.

Comment: oh, it is  not necessary that there is growth. the value can go down from previous month. in feb for exaple the value could be higher than in june

Comment: `apply(dt, 1, function(x) (x[1] - (y<-tail(na.omit(x),1)))/y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution. You only need to keep the sequence of months (columns) as they are so that we could use `y` value for their time spans:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dt %>%
  mutate(res = pmap(dt, ~ {x <- c(...)[-1]
  y <- c(...)[-1][which.min(abs(..1 - c(...)[-1]))]
  (..1 - y) / y}))

  june may april march feb  res
1    5   1     2     3   4 0.25
2    6  NA     2     3  NA    1
3    7   1     2    NA  NA  2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use coalesce:

```
dt %>%
   mutate(res = invoke(coalesce, rev(cur_data())),
          res = (june - res)/res)

  june may april march feb  res
1    5   1     2     3   4 0.25
2    6  NA     2     3  NA 1.00
3    7   1     2    NA  NA 2.50
```